# WPF Combobox - The object name being set as well as the value

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Morning,

I apologise in advance if this is a duplicate question, I am not really sure what is wrong so I don't really know what to search!

However, I have set a Combobox in XAML as

```
  <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Width="120"
    Text="{Binding PV.Loc}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding PV.Loc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
     <ComboBoxItem>.</ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding GetVer}"/>
  </ComboBox>
```

When I go to select the GetVer value (The property is a string) I get the following:

> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: The GetVer value

However, when I choose the dot, it sets correctly.

Sure its an easy one, what do I need to change?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do. your code doesn't look like normal databinding on a combo box. usually when you are using databinding on a ComboBox you do not use ComboBoxItems. are you trying to present a lookup table with a text search option?

Comment: I agree, I would normally use a enum or an ItemSource, but for this example the user can either select a dot or the version from a property in my ViewModel. so one of the items needs to bind to my property if you understand?

Comment: check out my code. it should work for your case. you can build your collection in the vm any way you want. this is why VMs exist, to make XAML simpler. include dot and version in that list. any time the version changes, update the list and call property changed on the list. it should refresh in the UI with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property

```
 <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" DisplayMemberPath="value"   />
 </ComboBox>
```

Also you should not use `<ComboBoxItem>.</ComboBoxItem>` if you are binding data.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I use a dot as pat of my databinding then? its an additional choice for the user, it wont be part of my model.

Comment: @user3428422 I guess you need a default value, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535747/set-default-value-in-wpf-combobox

Answer (score 0):

Set [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) property of Combo.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this while data-binding? you don't need ComboBoxItems...

```
//model
class DummyModel{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Value{get;set;}
}
//view-model
class DemoVM:INotifyPropertyChanged{
    private int selId;
    //you can build the list any way you want (even with hardcoded values...)
    public List<DummyModel> Items{get{return new List<DummyModel>();}}
    public int SelectedId{
        get{return selId;}
        set{
            if(selId==value)return;
            selId=value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedId");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name){
        //raise event here
    }
}
//view
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}"
    SelectedValuePath="Id" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
    IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Value">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Looks good but trouble is my . (dot) isnt in my ItemSource. I could put it in, but like not too. but I will sue the example if I don't find another way around it

Comment: what's the dot for? if it's for 'no selection' you don't even have to put it in the list. you just put the version, change the selId to a nullable and in the xaml you delete the CB text. on the VM side it should recod the null value and you should know no selection was made.

Comment: basically, if the user selects . the item will go to the root folder on the computer, if the selects GetVer, it will go to the folder of that version selected on the computer, its a late change so I think I might need to update the model!